# Sort array with custom order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of ids order say

```
order = [5,2,8,6]
```

and another array of hash

```
 [{id: 2,name: name2},{id: 5,name: name5}, {id: 6,name: name6}, {id: 8,name: name8}]
```

I want it sorted as

```
[{id: 5,name: name5},{id: 2,name: name2}, {id: 8,name: name8}, {id: 6,name: name6}]
```

What could be best way to implement this? I can implement this with iterating both and pushing it to new array but looking for better solution.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
arr = [  
         {:id=>2, :name=>"name2"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"name5"}, 
         {:id=>6, :name=>"name6"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"name8"}
      ]

order = [5,2,8,6]

arr.sort_by { |a| order.index(a[:id]) }
# => [{:id=>5, :name=>"name5"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"name2"}, 
#{:id=>8, :name=>"name8"}, {:id=>6, :name=>"name6"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Enumerable#in_order_of (Rails 7+)

---

Starting from **Rails 7**, there is a new method [Enumerable#in_order_of](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-in_order_of).

A quote right from the official Rails docs:

> in_order_of(key, series)

> Returns a new `Array` where the order has been set to that provided in the `series`, based on the `key` of the objects in the original enumerable.

```rb
[ Person.find(5), Person.find(3), Person.find(1) ].in_order_of(:id, [ 1, 5, 3 ])
=> [ Person.find(1), Person.find(5), Person.find(3) ]
```

> If the `series` include keys that have no corresponding element in the `Enumerable`, these are ignored. If the `Enumerable` has additional elements that aren't named in the `series`, these are not included in the result.

---

It is not perfect in a case of hashes, but you can consider something like:

```
require 'ostruct'

items = [{ id: 2, name: 'name2' }, { id: 5, name: 'name5' }, { id: 6, name: 'name6' }, { id: 8, name: 'name8' }]

items.map(&OpenStruct.method(:new)).in_order_of(:id, [5,2,8,6]).map(&:to_h)
# => [{:id=>5, :name=>"name5"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"name2"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"name8"}, {:id=>6, :name=>"name6"}]
```

---

**Sources:**

- Official docs - [Enumerable#in_order_of](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-in_order_of).
- PR - [Enumerable#in_order_of #41333](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41333).
- [Rails 7 adds Enumerable#in_order_of](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-7-adds-enumerable-in-order-of).